# How to read the table styles using apache POI from powerpoint

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am trying to read the table styles that is in a pptx template. 
Tried using `XSLFTableStyle xslfTableStyle = xslfTableStyles.getStyles()` but that returns empty list.

I am able to see the file which has the table styles in the pptx package in the location ppt/tableStyles.xml which has the styles for all the available tables and also the selected style for this template.

Even if I write some custom code to read this xml, I don't see a way to create a table in a slide using this style. `XSLFTable tbl = tableSlide.createTable();` this does not take any style inputs

Any out of the box way to create a table using the available table style?

Think this is not yet developed by Apache POI team, should be in their roadmap

Thanks,